# How to set remaining minutes counter in php

Tags: php, timer

i have a bot that refresh every 2 seconds and reply to links, and register the data in a txt file by each username so that it wont keep replying when it refreshes like this

```
$log = fopen($user_file,"a",1);
$data = $date.'-'.$link_data.'|';

fwrite($log, $data);    
fclose($log);

return;
```

and the user is allowed 1 link in 5 minutes which is set in the included config.php as $limit_link

when a user post a link before the 5 minutes are over he gets a msg that also register to the same xml file. i need the reply to be that "you can only post 1 link every 5 minutes, you can post again in 'minutes left'.

how can i do that ?

thanks in advance

Comment: I think better idea is use `callback` or `session` (for secure with token).

Comment: By checking if it was less than 5 minutes ago and sending him that error message

Comment: i didnt get your edit suggestion, can you please explain as i'm not a php guru :)
thanks

Comment: @Anigel, i already did that, he gets the message, i need the time left, as he posted 3.5 minutes ago, so he should get u can post again in 1.5 minutes, or 90 seconds ! thanks

Comment: @MaciejCzyżewski, i'm really sorry but i'm not a php guru, can you explain ?!
thanks

Answer (score 0):

If your trying to play with timers and stuffs with php, I suggest you should play with it along with an AJAX script.

If you ever tried using jquery ajax, everything would be much easier for you...

Comment: i think it should be easy in php it self but i dont know how ! it should be something like time for that link in xml file - current time or something like that !
thanks

Answer (score 0):

Simple example:

```
<?php
    // Start session
    session_start();

    // Hashing metod... you can use tokens
    function stupidEncode($string){
        return base64_encode($string);
    }

    function stupidDecode($string){
        return base64_decode($string);
    }

    // Now time for launch DateTime() machine
    $date = new DateTime();
    $date = $date->getTimestamp(); /*** We love timestamp! ***/

    if( (stupidDecode($_SESSION['date']) + 60) < $date ){
        // If it's after 1 minute
        $_SESSION['date'] = stupidEncode($date);

        echo "You are late...";
    }else{
        // If it's before 1 minute
        echo "OMG! What are you doing!";
    }
```